# Can I open an RESP for myself and transfer to my children's RESP account later?

Tags: canada, resp

Is it possible to open an RESP for myself today and when I have children, transfer the balance to my children's RESP account to receive annual CESG payments?

Comment: You can if you are under 17 years old. Anybody can open RESP except corporations/organizations/... but to receive CESG, there are strict rules.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely **no**.

A RESP can be opened **only by a older parent**. The RESP has to be opened before the child turns 16 years old not 17 years old.
Check this link: http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/resp-reee/menu-eng.html